# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [xhtml]

Tags: jsf, illegalargumentexception, url-pattern

I am trying to deploy a very simple & my first JSF application (following a [really good tutorial by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html)) on glassfish local server. I completed all the steps to create the application. And when I tried to deploy the application on the glassfish server, it just failed with the following exception message:-

```
    cannot Deploy Playground
    Deployment Error for module: Playground: Exception while deploying the app : 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [xhtml]
```

Could anyone explain where is the fault and how can I amend it ?

Comment: How is your `url-pattern` declared in your web.xml for Faces Servlet?

Comment: `<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>xhtml</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a valid url-pattern. You can arrange the mapping as prefix mapping or extension mapping (from the [JSF 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html)):

**Prefix mapping:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name> faces-servlet-name </servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Extension mapping:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name> faces-servlet-name </servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `<url-pattern>` must either have an extension matching (starts with a `*`) or prefix matching (starting with `/`) included, not just `xhtml`.

Here's how I did mine.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Vote up for beeing the first commenter to this question.

Answer (score 3):

The rules for servlet mappings are covered in the [Servlet 3.0 specs](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315):

> **Specification of Mappings**
>
> In the Web application deployment
>   descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a `/` character and ending with a `/*`
>     suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a `*.` prefix is used as an extension
>     mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>     application's context root, i.e.,
>     requests of the form
>     `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In
>     this case the path info is `/` and the
>     servlet path and context path is empty
>     string ("").
> - A string containing only the `/` character indicates the "default"
>     servlet of the application. In this
>     case the servlet path is the request
>     URI minus the context path and the
>     path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

When you encounter this error, check your web.xml and any mapping annotations ([WebServlet](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html#urlPatterns%28%29), [WebFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html#urlPatterns%28%29), etc.)

You can find recommendations for JSF servlet mapping in the [JSF 2.0 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314).

> When using extension mapping the
>   following mapping is recommended, but
>   not required:
>
> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
> <servlet-name> faces-servlet-name </servlet-name>
> <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```