# Why does my Spring MVC application not work when changing the server mapping?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I'm working on the Spring MVC "FitnessTracker" application outlined on Pluralsight. Below is my "web.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FitnessTracker/*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

The above makes Tomcat generate a bunch of exceptions, starting with

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
```

But when I change what's between the `<url-pattern>` tag to `*.html`, it works fine. Why is that?

Note: My goal is to try to make my app's controller run when I type /FitnessTracker/greeting.html, instead of /greeting.html. I am using Intellij IDEA, and doing Maven project with Tomcat 7.0 as my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application runs @ http://localhost:9090/**FitnessTracker/greeting.html** URL . FitnessTracker is application root context and **greeting**.html is mapped to Hello controller method. Please see below.

[image]

Could you please post the web.xml and controller mapping .

Answer (score 1):

The original code runs at the URL - http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/greeting.html. SO I am not sure why you need to change web.xml for that.

Also the URL pattern you are trying to use "/FitnessTracker/*.html" is not valid.
More details here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5441862/6352160